# How should I handle having applied to a company my current consultancy company may work with?

Tags: job-search, resignation

I have a very unusual situation at work:

I am currently working for a consultancy firm. Since I am not very happy at my job I have considered a few times to leave. Last week I applied for another
job (no response yet) at, say company X. Yesterday, one of my managers called me to say that I will be going to a new project in two weeks at company X 
(probably same department as I was applying for).

This really is a coincidence because I know that the firm I'm working for is not much involved with company X and above that company X is abroad.

At this point I'm not sure what to think about this situation. On one hand this is good news as I get to know company X very well and I get the
chance to network. On the other hand, company X has received my application so I am not sure what they will think about the fact that I will be working there
as a consultant soon.

What should I say if a recruiter of company X calls me?

Suppose that they reject my application because they find me unsuitable then it will be weird since I am then still working there as a consultant.

I think the best way to handle this is to be truly honest with company X when the time comes?

Any tips and hints would very welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: Most important you should look into your current contract and (by any chance) the contract between company X and your current employer. Usually consultancy firms have a penalty when an emploee changes directly to the client. At least you should talk to company X about that too.

Comment: What is your problem more precisely ? Not knowing how to deal with a recruiter of a company you have as a client ? Not knowing what to do if they find out you applied and have them as clients ? Should you tell a client of your current company that you applied to a position at their company ?

Comment: @sh5164; you hit the spot there. I am not sure what to do in all these kind of situations. I may have the possibility (via the website) to revoke my application since it has only been a couple of days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your situation is not really easy, you probably don't want to burn bridges with your current company while not burning bridges with the company you are applying to.

Here is what you can do :

### Tell Company X you applied for a position at their company

The fact that you work for them could be an advantage as much as a deal breaker. If you do your job well, it might get you in a better position than most candidates since they will know you are reliable.
The downside is that if they reject your application it might be awkward.

### Not tell Company X you applied

No awkwardness while you are working for them, but if they find out you applied they might think you didn't tell them for bad reasons, such as not wanting to have your current work related to what you intend to do at their company.

### Cancel your application...To apply later

Could be a good solution, you are not an applicant during your work for this client, avoiding the awkwardness and all the "what if ?" that seems to happen to you right now and reapply when you work for another client.

When being interviewed later you can precise that you have worked for their company already as a client of your former company and liked the culture/work environment/missions, gaining even more "interview points".

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have revoked/canceled my application and since the application deadline was yesterday it looks like I was still in time to do this. Hopefully, everything will be OK now. I am fortunate that HR did not yet contacted me.